# Procedure don´t run correctly

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I create simple procedure who insert data from one table to another table. When I press execute It only mark as successfull but it don´t do any. But If I get a piece of code and press executed, it runs correctly: there are an images of what occur:[image]
and If I select piece of code:

[image: it runs correctly so something with m] I think  try catch is wrong. Can anyone help me? Regards

**Store:**

```
 BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    --Delete all registers of Proceso.srcUnidadesPresupuestadas 
    DELETE FROM Proceso.srcUnidadesPresupuestadas 

    --Insert in table Proceso.srcUnidadesPresupuestadas 
    INSERT INTO Proceso.srcUnidadesPresupuestadas (
    IdCliente,IdCentro,IdNumeroParte,keyNumeroParte,keyCliente,
    keyCentro,Periodo,Mes,UnidadesPresupuestadas,
    mdOrigenCarga,mdUsuarioCarga,mdFechaCarga,bActivo) 
    SELECT
        keyCliente,keyCentro,keyMaterial,keyCliente,keyCliente,
        keyCentro,Periodo,Mes,UnidadesPresupuestadas,
        mdOrigenCarga,mdUsuarioCarga,mdFechaCarga,bActivo FROM Proceso.tmpUnidadesPresupuestadas
    --FROM
    --    #tmpUnidadesPresupuestadas


 COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        DECLARE
            @ERROR_SEVERITY INT,
            @ERROR_STATE    INT,
            @ERROR_NUMBER   INT,
            @ERROR_LINE     INT,
            @ERROR_MESSAGE  NVARCHAR(4000);

        SELECT
            @ERROR_SEVERITY = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @ERROR_STATE    = ERROR_STATE(),
            @ERROR_NUMBER   = ERROR_NUMBER(),
            @ERROR_LINE     = ERROR_LINE(),
            @ERROR_MESSAGE  = ERROR_MESSAGE();

        RAISERROR('Msg %d, Line %d, :%s',
            @ERROR_SEVERITY,
            @ERROR_STATE,
            @ERROR_NUMBER,
            @ERROR_LINE,
            @ERROR_MESSAGE);
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: What happens when you `EXEC` the sproc?

Comment: It run and return `Command(s) completed successfully.` but it don´t do anything @TZHX

Comment: Take out the `set nocount on;`

Comment: Are you sure it does not do anything? You've got "SET NOCOUNT ON;", that is why you don't get the row counts.

Comment: try to place the error handling code just at the beginning of the catch(even before the if @@trancount), just to check if it shows anything. Ps: you're saying it doesn't do anything ,just because of the output message, or are you CHECKING THE TABLE?

Comment: I think we need the definition of `but it don´t do any`. Did you `select * from  Proceso.srcUnidadesPresupuestadas` after the procedure executed to see if there are any rows in the table?

Comment: Yes I do and I didn´t got anything, but If I select insert code and execute it I have all values

Answer (score 1):

When you click on execute after writing procedure code you are only compiling/creating the procedure. To run the procedure you have to execute the following statement :

```
Use <database name>;
Exec <procedure name>;
```

Comment: I thought that could be the problem but then I thought... nah

Comment: where should I use tha statements?

Comment: Write them in any SQL query window after connecting to server